# Intersection of a collection of regular submanifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $\psi_\alpha:M\rightarrow \mathbb R^k$ is a smooth submersion with constant rank (regular map) for all $\alpha\in \Delta$.

Is it true that $\bigcap\limits_{\alpha\in \Delta} \psi_{\alpha}^{-1}(0)$ a submanifold of $M$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Example: $M= \mathbb R^2$, $\psi_1 (x, y) = y$ and $\psi_2 (x, y) =  y-\phi(x)$, where $\phi$ is a bump function so that $\phi\ge 0$ and $\{ y: \phi(y)>0\} = (0,1)$. Then both $\psi_i$ are of full rank,

$$\psi^{-1}_1(0) = \{ (x, 0): x\in \mathbb R\}, \ \ \ \psi_2^{-1}(0) = \{ (x, \phi(x)) : x\in \mathbb R\}$$

and
$$\psi_1^{-1}(0) \cap \psi^{-1}_2(0)= \{ (x, 0): x\notin (0,1)\}$$

is not a submanifold of $\mathbb R^2$.